# What is the most appropriate set-up to pressurize air in a closed, confined space?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, heating-systems

Assume that we have hot air in a confined closed space of 36 m^3. This hot air will be distributed trough a piping network of 500 m to be blown on trees. What is the most appropriate set-up to increase air pressure in this closed, confined space so that it can be distributed through the pipe network and then blown?

Comment: defined "pressurized air."  Low pressure air is distributed through ducts using fans; high pressure air is distributed through pipes using compressors. 36m^3 could be either.  "Hot" isn't a very good specification, either.  We also need to know how much of this air you plan to supply.

Comment: that small volume of air will be used in seconds, so how will you heat more air?

Comment: What do you mean by "that small volume of air will be used in second"?

Comment: I changed "pressurize air" to  "increase air pressure".

Comment: It would be very helpful if you explain what you're trying to accomplish, and how you've arrived at the values you specify.

Comment: I want to distribute hot air through a piping network (around 500 m) to blow on tress during frost periods. To that end, I need a set up to compress it so that it can be distributed and then blown.